# Delete data between date range in Data Flow

Tags: azure, date, delete-row, azure-data-factory

I have a data Flow that reads from Parquet files, does some filtering and then loads into a Delta Lake. The data flow would run multiple times and I don't want duplicate data in my Delta Lake. To safeguard this, I thought to implement a delete-insert mechanism- Find the minimum and maximum date of the incoming data and delete all the data in destination (delta) that falls under this range. Once deleted, all filtered incoming data would be inserted into delta lake.

From documentation, I saw that I need to add policies at row level in an Alter Row Tx to mark that particular row for deletion. I added Delete-If condition as - `between(toDate(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toDate("2021-12-22T01:49:57", 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toDate("2021-12-23T01:49:57", 'MM/dd/yyyy'))` where date is a column in incoming data.

However, in data preview of Alter Row Tx, all the rows are being marked for insertion and 0 for deletion when there definitely are records that belong to that range.

I suspect that Delete-If condition does not work the way I want it to. In that case, how do I implement deletion between data range in Data Flow with Delta as destination ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ADF what to do with the other portions of the timestamp (it's not a date type yet). Try this:

toString(toTimestamp('2021-12-22T01:49:57', 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the entire expression to - 
between(toString(toTimestamp(date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toString(toTimestamp("2021-12-22T01:49:57", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toString(toTimestamp("2021-12-23T01:49:57", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))

Would that be correct? Its a string comparison now.

Comment: If you need to cast it to date, then add toDate()